# How to generate a type from an array of object value in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, types, enums

I am having an array of routes as such :

```
export const routes = [
  { name: 'Home', component: HomeScreen },
  { name: 'CreateProgram', component: CreateProgramScreen },
  { name: 'AddExercises', component: AddExercisesScreen },
]
```

I'd like to generate the kind of type alias as below programmatically from the name of the route:

`type RouteNames = 'Home' | 'CreateProgram' | 'AddExercises'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type the array `as const` so it doesn't get automatically widened, and then you can use `[number]` on its type to get a union of all object types, and then access `["name"]` to get to type of the `name` property.

```
export const routes = [
  { name: 'Home', component: HomeScreen },
  { name: 'CreateProgram', component: CreateProgramScreen },
  { name: 'AddExercises', component: AddExercisesScreen },
] as const;
type RouteNames = (typeof routes)[number]["name"];
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick answer @CertainPerformance yet it seems to result into a `string` type only and doesn't prevent me from passing wrong route names.

Comment: Like the answer says and the snippet shows, you need to type the array `as const`.

Comment: Correct, thanks for highlighting this detail to me